# MDX Calculated Measure - counts between start and end dates

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a dimension "Company" which has a member "CompanyName" and a measure group "CompanyMembership" which has measures "StartDate" and "EndDate". How do I count the number of companies that have membership for a date or month or year? I also have a user hierarchy Date.Calendar (like the one in Adventure Works).

If the date current member represents a month the member value will be the first day of the month and I only care if the membership covers that day. If a year the member value will be the first day of the year and I only care if the membership covers that day.

Here is some pseudocode for what I would like:
 sum( if (Measures.StartDate <= Date.Calendar.Value <= Measures.EndDate) then 1 else 0)

I would like to keep StartDate and EndDate in the same fact table row (not split into two rows - one with StartDate and one with EndDate) but would be willing to change the schema if there's no other way.

How can I write this expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a method for doing this in your current schema, but you should really consider making Membership a time dimension.  That would make answering "was this company a member on this date?" much easier.

Comment: Do you mean use a single date for each date in the range instead of a range like this: if the the range is 1/1/2012 - 12/31/2012 then a row for 1/1/2012, 1/2/2012, ..., 12/31/2012? If so that is a good idea but I don't think it will work for me because of the size of the tables and wide date ranges.

Comment: That's the idea.  You shouldn't have to make a new fact table, though.  If SSAS doesn't have a way to build a time dimension based on a pair of dates in the fact table, then you could create a view to do the expansion.  It's been a few years since I built a cube, so I'm not sure of the most elegant method.

Comment: Using a view sounds like a good option. I worry about the space usage because I have this same type of relationship multiple times with tables having 100,000,000+ rows and date ranges of 10+ years (for example, members have membership as well). I am hoping to get an mdx function working to save the space but then the performance might make it unusable. I will test the view and post back. thanks.

Comment: Using a view works great. I will try the other storage options if space becomes an issue in the partitions. Thanks Simon!